# get default name of a select box

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find which selectbox is set to default using jquery.

I have this much setup.

```
var selectBoxes = $('select', this.el);
selectBoxes.each(function(){
    console.log( "val = ", $(this).val());
});
```

This give me the default value of each select box but I'm trying to find which option this belongs to.

Comment: Use `select[i].selectedIndex` and `select[i].options[select[i].selectedIndex]` to get the option.

Comment: Thank you Rob, that solved what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

It should be..

```
var selectBoxes = $('select', this.el);
selectBoxes.children().each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating my answer at the OP's comments:

```
//Select every `<select>` which is a child of this.el, and loop through it
var selectBoxes = $('select', this.el);
selectBoxes.each(function(){
    //`this` points to the select element
    // The following declaration will define a HTMLOptionElement
    var selectedOption = select.options[this.selectedIndex];
    var value = selectedOption.value;      //Recommended
    //Alternatively: $(selectedOption).val();
});
```

If you want to use jQuery methods on the selected option element, wrap the object in a jQuery constructor: `$(selectedOption)`.